# Makefile: Multiple targets, one dependency

Tags: c, linux, makefile

I have a script that generates 2 code files (For example, src1.c, src2.c) according to another code file (say origin.h).
I use a makefile to build them.
Now, I want the script to be executed when src1.c OR src2.c is older that origin.h.

What is the best way to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make src1.c and src2.c jointly dependent on origin.h:

```
src1.c src2.c : origin.h
        build-sources
```

Comment: Another option is to make a DUMMY target that depends on both `.c` files.

Comment: This can be problematic if parallel make (`make -j`) is used. In this case, `build-sources` could be executed twice. The only solution I've found for this is using the `.NOTPARALLEL:` Makefile dependency. Not elegant, but it does work.